# No matching calls when verify a call in unit test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-http, dart-test

I want to unit test and check a method makes correct http request. So I create the bellow test:

```
class MockRequest extends Mock implements http.Request {}
```

then

```
      test('make correct http request', () async {
        final uri = baseUri.replace(path: 'account/send_email');

        final response = MockResponse();
        when(
          () => response.statusCode,
        ).thenReturn(200);

        when(
          () => response.stream,
        ).thenAnswer(
          (_) => http.ByteStream.fromBytes('OK'.codeUnits),
        );

        final request = MockRequest();
  
        when(
          () => request.method,
        ).thenReturn('GET');

        when(
          () => request.body,
        ).thenReturn('{"email":"$validEmail"}');
        
        when(
          () => request.headers,
        ).thenReturn({
          'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
        });

        when(
          () => request.url,
        ).thenReturn(uri);

        when(() => client.send(any())).thenAnswer((_) async => response);

        try {
          await sut.sendEmail(validEmail);
        } catch (_) {}
        verify(() => client.send(request)).called(1);
      });
```

and here is my method:

```
  Future<void> sendEmail(String email) async {
    if (!EmailValidator.validate(email)) throw InvalidEmailFormatException();
    final requestUrl = baseUri.replace(path: '/account/send_email');
    final request = http.Request(RequestMethod.get.method, requestUrl);
    request.headers.clear();
    request.headers.addAll({"Content-type": "text/plain"});
    request.body = '{"email":"$email"}';
    try {
      final response = await _client.send(request);

      if (response.statusCode != 200) {
        throw HttpException(
            'Response statuse code = ${response.statusCode}, Reason phrase = ${response.reasonPhrase}',
            uri: requestUrl);
      }
      final responseBodyString = await response.stream.bytesToString();
      final reponseJson =
          jsonDecode(responseBodyString) as Map<String, dynamic>;
      final code = reponseJson['code'];
      if (code != 200) {
        throw ServerException(code, uri: requestUrl);
      }
    } on SocketException {
      rethrow;
    } on FormatException {
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

I get the `No matching calls. All calls: MockClient.send(GET https://test.webapi.odinpool.com:1989/account/send_email)`  message. What did I do wrong?

I tought to use `Equatable` package to compare request both in the actual method and in the test, but i don't know how to use equatable with mock object.Since the request object didn't inject to API class so how we can ensure that this two request object was same?